# matplotlib changing colour of dataset

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

iris = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\MACHINE\Desktop\iris.csv', names=['sepal_length', 'sepal_width',         
'petal_length', 'petal_width', 'class'])

colors = {'Versicolor':'r', 'Setosa':'g', 'Virginica':'b'}
# create a figure and axis
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# plot each data-point
for i in range(len(iris['sepal_length'])):
    ax.scatter(iris['sepal_length'][i], iris['sepal_width'][i], color= colors[iris['class'][i]])
# set a title and labels
ax.set_title('Iris Dataset')
ax.set_xlabel('sepal_length')
ax.set_ylabel('sepal_width')


ax.scatter(iris['sepal_length'][i], iris['sepal_width'][i], color= colors[iris['class'][i]])
```

KeyError: 'class'
I am new to python most probably it is a syntax error.I have also given the link of website I was copying the code from
https://towardsdatascience.com/introduction-to-data-visualization-in-python-89a54c97fbed

Comment: Please add the full error message.

Comment: Add the full error message. But your iris variable doesn't contain a ['class'] index.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(len(iris['sepal_length'])):
    ax.scatter(iris['sepal_length'][i], 
    iris['sepal_width'[i],color=colors.get(iris['class'][i]) )
```

use get method instead